# Python Split elements from a tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the input as shown below.

```
(1,50.04,Rs.42)
```

I would like to get the following output

```
a = 1
b = 50.04
c = 42
```

Updated Input -

```
['(1,50.04,Rs.42)', '(10,14.71,Rs.82)', '(11,44.19,Rs.93)']
```

Comment: `a, b, c, = (1, 50.04, Rs.42)` is how you unpack tuples. Although I don't know where the `Rs.` is coming from or what you want to do with it.

Comment: @nawarkhede yes how can i get all the three values in the tuple to different variables.

Comment: @corykramer that did not work.

Comment: Well you should start with the fact that your original input isn't valid python syntax

Comment: i have updated the input i am giving.

Comment: check out this code : https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9085068